# Packing numbers efficiently

Tags: c#

I have `n` numbers in the range of `0..m-1`. `m` doen't have to be a power of 2.
The most efficient way to pack them into a stream of bytes will require exactly `log2(m)*n` bits rounded up.
I get the numbers as a `List<int>` and `m` as `int m`. How can I pack it into `List<byte>` not exceeding the size of `log2(m)*n/8`?
After the packing is done how can get the numbers back having the `List<byte>` and `int n, m`?

Comment: Please elaborate further and include some examples if you can.

Comment: Can we conclude that m <= 2^32 ? (never mind)

Comment: I can't... I don't have example because I don't know how to pack the numbers. by information theory, `n` numbers of range `0..m-1` can take a maximum of `log(m)*n` size for any case.

Comment: And is this homework? Then please tag it as such.

Comment: No, m <= int.Max. it can be any value in between.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: its not homework, its for an application I'm writing that needs to compress streams of enumerations.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I haven't tried anything because I have no clue what algorithm to use for this.

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, but packing numbers is vaguely reminiscent of **[Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)**, which however uses variable-length codes.

Comment: "needs to compress streams" - then (why) is a `List<Byte>` a good target?

Comment: @stakx: Huffman coding requires a distribution table and will produce some codes longer than `log(m)*n`.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: just for algorithm cleanness, what I will actually do is write this byte by byte into a file

Comment: If I had to do this in a business-case I would not bother with any bit-fiddling but write `int`s to a Compression stream. That's why the homework question popped up. And only when the volume is large and log2(m) << 32 .

Comment: @Dani, true, but it also produces shorter codes. As I said, it's not *exactly* what the OP asked for, but my point is that Huffman coding should be effective in "packing" numbers (see this question's title); it's been used for loss-less data compression, after all.

Comment: Dani: Try a simple case by hand first. For instance, let's say that you know the numbers are all smaller than 8. How would you pack the numbers 2,4,2,5,2,6,2,7 into 24 bits? How would you read them back out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework?

Generally speaking, when you have N numbers in 0..M-1 range, this means that you have ONE number in 0..M*N-1 range.  Representing this requires equal or fewer bits, `log2(M*N)`, then the case when the numbers are encoded separately.

Next, if you know something else about the numbers (their distribution, or their dependency on one another), you can try to apply various compressing schemas.  When the distribution is know, Huffman or similar encodings might be the simplest approach.  When the sequential dependency is known, LZ(W) or similar would be the approach.  And so on.

**EDIT**: answering the question in comment about how to store/write/read such a number.  You can store the number in various forms.  Byte arrays seem to be one (if not the) most efficient way to do so.  Here's a quick example on how to do that using [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), which is close enough to memory efficiency of the byte array, but with some convenient operations on top.  You may want to re-write this using more appropriate storage:

```
int[] Ms = new int[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };
int N = 42;
System.Numerics.BigInteger x = new System.Numerics.BigInteger();

System.Numerics.BigInteger power = 1;

// composing the pack:
foreach (int s in Ms) {
    x += power * s;
    power *= N;
}

// reading the pack:
//  extracting i'th number:
int i = 2;
power = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow(N, i);
int result = (int)((x / power) % N);
```

Comment: The `0..M*N-1` number seems the right direction. How Can I write/make such a number in c#?

Comment: @Dani: edited the answer to include the example of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Treat the list of numbers as the digits of a base-m number.

Comment: How do I convert a base-m number into a stream of bytes?

Comment: MRAB means that you would represent each number in the range as a bit, sequentially. If the number is present the bit should be 1, if it is not you leave the bit 0. So if your sequence of numbers in range 0..15 (2 bytes) is {1,3,4,5,9,15} the storage would look like this in binary: `1000 0010 0011 1010`.

Comment: @Joel: I was actually thinking along the lines of what @Rom wrote, but I didn't know about BigInteger (I'm a Python person; Python ints behave like that), so I would've gone the long way round and implemented it using byte arrays. :-(